# Notice: Undefined variable: this in C:\dev\workspaces\adxweb\library\Adx\Datagrid\class.eyedatagrid.inc.php on line 885

Tags: php, javascript

Hii,

When I am trying to use eyedatagrid, I am getting the following error message and the datagrid is not displayed, any idea why I am getting this error message, thanx

> Notice:  Undefined variable: this in
>   Datagrid\class.eyedatagrid.inc.php on
>   line 885

and line 885 holds this ----

```
 if ($this)
    {
        $page = $this->page;
        $order = (($this->order) ? implode(':', $this->order) : '');
        $filter = (($this->filter) ? implode(':', $this->filter) : '');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function in static context (as I just deduced from the code you didn't show).

```
EyeDataGrid::printJavascript()
```

This is why `$this` isn't present.

Change the `if ($this)` into `if (isset($this))` or disable the debug mode if you don't want notices.